# Sitecore Prefetch Cache Size Different after upgradation

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore9

I have done the Sitecore upgrading from 8.1 to 9.0 Update 2. I see there is an issue on the prefetch cache.

On the old version the webdb prefetch cache will go till 6GB but on the upgraded version it is not crossing 1.5GB.

Sitecore 8.1 Instance
[image]

Sitecore 9.0 Upgraded Instance

[image]

Comment: pub is not a default db, is this your web database? is there any custom config related to the prefetch cache. also take a look at the config /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and search for <database id="pub" are you prefetching the same?

Comment: Yes we do have a custom database for the live version and we are using a prefetch cache for the same.

Answer (score 0):

There was a huge investment in caching architecture redesign, I'll bring up a few things that were changed:

1) Game changer - [Sitecore.Interning.config](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/Stop-wasting-memory) that allows reusing repeatable immutable objects (like strings, IDs) - we keep much less duplicate objects in memory now out of the box. You could see the difference by disabling interning in the aforementioned config.

2) Introduce `Sitecore.Caching.Interfaces.ISizeTrackable` interface that should help entities know their size better - that is very true for PreferechData; it will even give you different sizes for 32/64 bit app pool setting (as pointer size is different).

3) Introduce `Sitecore.Common.ITrimExcess` interface that allows a collection to shrink upon a major portion of data is added (internally relies on [TrimExcess()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.trimexcess?view=netframework-4.8) APIs for List or HashList).

To sum up - much lower numbers are expected for core platform parts as those were carefully crafted :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you compared how much memory the `w3wp` process actually consumes? It looks like you have a similar amount of items in the cache. From what I can see in your screen shots, the cache is working as expected in both scenarios.

The cache size of each object is *estimated* through the `ICacheable.GetDataLength()` implementation of each cacheable object. This value isn't always accurate and sometimes it's actually quite far off. At least in previous versions of Sitecore, you could do a sum of the entire cache size column and get a total sum that's far greater than your `w3wp` process size.

If I recall right, Sitecore has changed how object sizes are estimated by default. You're probably seeing an effect of that.

Comment: The total cache in the admin shows as 3.6GB and the w3wp process is consuming around 9.7GB.

Comment: Also i tried remove the default entries in the prefetch configs (common.config and webdb.config) even then the cache size is 1.5GB and there is no variation at all.

Comment: Have you changed anything else in your solution? From what I can see in your screen shots, you actually have more items cached in 9.0 (95,653 objects) compated to 8.1 (89,916 objects). This is why I'm not sure you're actually chasing a real issue here. To me it still looks like the size figures are playing mind tricks.